# How to make resource dynamic routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I need to define route like this.

```
api/:some_entity_id/bla
api/:some_entity_id/bla/new
```

I can define this with get for each route. Can I manage to do this with resources because I need all crud actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it

```
scope '/api/:some_entity_id' do
  resources :bla
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix routes with a named parameter like this:

```
scope "api/:some_entity_id" do
  resources :bla
end
```